# is there a regex for parsing a string possible?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Consider the following string:

01500343014501044801

I want to parse this string and fill 6 variables with it, they are filled from a fixed length in the string.

Now instead of doing the obvious:

```
string s1 = s.Substring(0, 3);
//...
string s2 = s.Substring(7, 8);
//...
```

Im wondering if there's a regex possible for doing this? Or does the .NET framework have a something like sscanf in C?

Comment: possible, but will not make it any better. You will still have to assign each match to each string variable. I suggest sticking with the `Substring` approach

Comment: Seems like an abuse of regular expressions to me; which are not quick. I'd stick to .Substring if I were you.

Comment: yeah agreed, just trying to learn about the wonderful world of regexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you can specify length of blocks `(\d{5})(\d{4})(\d{7})(\d{4})` will capture 4 groups consisting of 5,4,7 and 4 digits respectfully.
Although comments to your question are spot on, RegEx will be slower.

Comment: it does not seem to work. This just matches the whole string and not 6 matches of different length: Regex.Matches(name, @"(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{1})")

Comment: then you are doing something wrong. Check this article out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
    var myNumber = "01500343014501044801";
    var m = Regex.Matches(myNumber, @"\d{3}");
```

Answer (score -1):

A quotation from Jamie Zawinski:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Using regular expressions is costly in terms of performance. I'd stick to substrings in your case as you're not using any of the pattern matching facilities that regular expressions offer.